# матрица переходов для цепи Маркова

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, матрицы

Имеется кваюратная иатрица А, требуется получить матрицу содержащую процентное содержание элементов в каждой строке.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array( [[1,2,3,4],[2,4,1,3],[3,4,1,2],[3,1,4,2]] )
P=np.array( [[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4],[0.2,0.4,0.1,0.3],[0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2]] )
```

Тут `P(i,j)=A(i,j)/sum(A(i))` без умножения на 100%. P- матрица переходов для цепи Маркова

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
P=A/A.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
P=A/A.sum(axis=1) делит столбцы  
потому что 
A.sum(axis=1) вектор строка
A.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1) вектор столбец
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё довольно просто. Только надо с номером оси угадать при суммировании. Я обычно просто пробую сначала `sum()` без аргументов, потом по очереди с `axis=0` и `axis=1`. В данном случае подходит `axis=1`:

```
P = A / A.sum(axis=1)
```